# Why can't Wacom tablet touch gesture work like Magic Trackpad

Tags: magic-trackpad

I recently got a Wacom graphic tablet, Wacom Intuos Art with multi-touch feature, this is my first ever graphic tablet, and I immediately fall in love with it, the stylus drawing side of it.

Here is the thing, before I buy, I am keep comparing it with Magic Trackpad's touch capabilities. The only gesture of the Wacom tablet that I feel really close to work like Magic Trackpad is two fingers fluid scrolling. The others, like mouse tracking with one finger, can't really track small movement nicely/precisely, only large movement will work well.

The tablet also provide four fingers swipe left/right to switch between desktop spaces. If you use Magic Mouse/Trackpad you can intercept in between the animation, you can reverse it if you want. But, the Wacom tablet kind of like just triggering the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> when you perform the gesture.

I am so new to graphic tablet, I want to know is there any 3rd party software/driver I can use to enhance the experience of this graphic tablet?

Answer (score 1):

Though I lack a Wacom tablet to test it myself, [this post](https://www.boastr.net/btt-0-731-alpha/) seems to indicate that [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) supports Wacom tablets to some degree.

[BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) has a variety of features that will allow you to configure and bind gestures to actions.

Comment: I checked that page as well, my conclusion is BTT is a great software but really not taking graphic tablet as first class citizen.

Comment: @KentLiau Unfortunately true: it wasn't designed with that in mind. You could write to the developer, he's been known to be quite receptive to feedback and active within various communities.